# Do i have to import anything to use drawPoint() in lua?

Tags: lua, drawing

So I am fairly new to lua and I am learning how to use it by making a checkers app for android. When I found out that I would have to make the circles myself without a function i decided to look for other ways and it looks like the drawPoint() function is the best answer. When I made an equation to try and test it I got a error with the draw point function. It says:

attempt to call global 'drawPoint'(a nil value)
stack traceback:
           main.lua54: in main chuck

am I missing something like do I have to import a library to use it? Thank you in advance and just for more background I was giving it the parameter of 2 ints.  Here is my whole code below

---

```
--All the essential values
local widget = require ("widget")
local redCount = 12
local blackCount = 12
local length = 40.05
local x = length / 2
local y = 80
local startX = x
local startY = y
local allowMoves = true

--Title Display
local title = display.newText("Checkers", display.contentCenterX, 10, native.systemFontBold, 40)

--Functions
local function checkWinner()
    if(redCount == 0) then
        display.newText("Black Team Wins!!!", display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 60, nativeSystemFontBold, 37)
    elseif(blackCount == 0) then
        display.newText("Red Team Wins!!!", display.contentCenterX, display.contentHeight - 60, nativeSystemFontBold, 40)
    end
end

--Making the board
for i = 1, 8, 1 
    do
        for k = 1, 4, 1
        do  
            if i % 2 == 1 then
                display.newRect( x, y, length, length, 30)

            else 
                display.newRect( x + length, y, length, length, 30)
            end
            x = x + (startX * 4)
        end
        y = y + length
        x = startX
    end

--Making the outline
display.newRect(startX, startY - (length / 2), length * 15, 3, 30)
display.newRect(startX, y - (length / 2), length * 15, 3, 30)
display.newRect(startX - (length / 2), startY, 3, length * 15, 30)
display.newRect(320.4, startY, 3, length * 15, 30)

--Making the actual peices
drawPoint(2,5)
```

---

Comment: drawPoint(2,5)                  -That is the line causing the issue sorry for such a simple question just not used to lua yet.

Comment: where did you get that function name drawPoint from? Lua does not have such a function. without knowing more about the environment you're programming in we cannot help you. are you using some SDK like Corona? You cannot write Android apps in Lua alone.

Comment: Yes I am using corona for this build and I have updated my post with my code. I'm sorry about not having all the extra information I am new to this site.

Comment: and why don't you use newCircle? I mean you're already using newRect. so I'd assume you know those functions. what is your actual problem?

Comment: a newCircle function.......

Comment: the purpose of this comment is not clear